# HttpClient PostAsync error: The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: php, laravel, vb.net, httpclient

I have a VB.net application that I need to connect to an API Controller coded in PHP with Laravel as the framework. I am getting the below error when the code hits PostAsync.

```
System.AggregateException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       at .Common.Web._Closure$__1._Lambda$__1() in C:\Users\...\Web.vb:line 82
  InnerException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
       InnerException: System.Net.WebException
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.ConnectStream.ReadWithoutValidation(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean abortOnError)
```

This is the code:

```
Private Shared Function MakeRequest(ByVal RequestedUrl As String, ByVal Params As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As Task(Of WebResponse)

            Return Threading.Tasks.Task(Of WebResponse).Factory.StartNew(
                Function()
                    Dim httpResponse As HttpResponseMessage = Nothing
                    Try
                        Using httpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()

                            Dim tmp As String = _httpMethod
                            If Not _apiUrl.EndsWith("/") Then
                                tmp = _httpMethod + "://"
                            End If

                            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)
                            Dim responseStatus As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = httpClient.PostAsync(tmp & _apiUrl, New FormUrlEncodedContent(Params))
                            httpResponse = responseStatus.Result
                            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

                            Dim responseContent As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String) = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                            Dim responseBody As String = responseContent.Result

                            Dim webResponse As WebResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of WebResponse)(responseBody)
                            Return webResponse

                        End Using
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        If httpResponse IsNot Nothing Then
                            Return New WebResponse(CInt(httpResponse.StatusCode).ToString(), "Error " + CInt(httpResponse.StatusCode).ToString() + ": " + ex.Message, Nothing)
                        Else
                            Return New WebResponse("500", ex.Message, Nothing)
                        End If
                    End Try
                End Function)

        End Function
```

I have tried everything I could find on google with the same error but nothing seems to work. I am using XAMPP v3.2.2 with Apache 2.4.37.0 and OpenSSL 1.1.1a.

The server doesn't seem to allow the client (VB.net app, using TLS 1.2) to connect and I am puzzled why. The Apache access logs don't help either. Note that I can connect to the API via Postman and it does the POST request successfully.

I really hope someone can shed some light on this as I am stuck here for days.

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? You have this: `[...] DirectCast(3072, System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)`, which suggests a .NET version prior to 4.5. But you're using HttpClient -- `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, if you need to set it, you have to do it before anything else (even the creation of the HttpClient object) -- Why are you not awaiting those async calls? -- Does the Server publish a valid certificate? -- What is `WebResponse`? Your own class? With the same name of a .NET class?

Comment: You should also mention the System version of the machine where this code is run

Comment: Are you 100% sure you get the correct URL?  The way you're constructing the url seems a little off.  What is _httpMethod?  Is that the actual Http Method (as in Get, Post etc) or the protocol (https eg)

Comment: @Jimi This is targeting .NET Framework 4. Should I not use HttpClient? Will try to assign SecurityProtocol before the creation of HttpClient. WebResponse is our own class. Will try to include await. Actually, this is not my code. This is from someone who's not in the company anymore. And this is working in production. I am just adding a parameter for the API which is why I was testing, then this error happened. The reason why I think there is something wrong with the Apache server.

This is running on Windows 11, x64.

Comment: @Hursey _httpMethod is the protocol. This is pulled from the database.